# SQL - How to check logic in an execute tasks in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a directory in SQL server of the current SSIS packages we have which would include the jobs they are connected to and in turn which table they would load. I am wondering is it possible to see any queries used in an SSIS package such as either the execute sql task or the table which the ssis package is moving data to. Currently have been using the following query which gives me good info but hoping to expand it to include any queries which are used within side SSIS.

```
SELECT event_message_id ,
            execution_path ,
            package_name ,
            package_path_full ,
            event_name ,
            message_source_name ,
            package_path
     FROM   internal.event_messages (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: _is it possible to see any queries used in an SSIS package_ Yes. The way I've done it in the past: 1. Get a list of every table in the database (from system catalogs) 2. For each table, open every .dtsx file and search for it. You can get more sophisticated and use regular expressions to work out whether the table is in a source or target component. Same goes for linking SQL Agent Jobs to SSIS packages: get the list of every package, then check SQL Agent job step definitions for that text.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for the above, Just on opening every dtsx file, do you mean by going into Integration service catalog and clicking into each of the SSIS Packages ? I dont see on option for opening so slighty confused on the step to take.

Comment: Use a script to do this. For example, export all package as a *.ispac file, unzip it and inspect the .dtsx files. Do this with a script (say powershell or python). Don't do it manually.

Comment: In the past we have used a [naming standard](https://sqlkover.com/ssis-naming-conventions-2-0/) for ssis, like DFT - load schema table, SQL - stored procedure name.  Then in the ssisdb logs we can see stats on table load, rows, and from the task name we can understand the table

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, i am giving a go at using powershell to capture this. Havent used it before but there does seem to be some tips online for it. Will post an update if i manage to get a script which can return the data within a package